# Tableau Line chart with shading

Tags: tableau-api

I'm tracking the VIX here for example and I'd like to have a line chart showing the daily prices but with the background shaded according to the tiers broken down in the legend.  Is something like this possible in Tableau?  As I have it now, the different tiers are broken down via different color coded lines but I'd like to just have a black line, with the various points and the tiers shaded in the background instead.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Could you try to show the desired result by some image editing or within a different tool like Excel etc?

Comment: also a sample workbook available some where?